# WiFi getting blocked, not sure why

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, network-manager

I am not sure what is causing it. Recently I started actively using UFW / gufw, maybe after that the wifi connection issue started. My WiFi will try to connect infinitely, but will never get connected. Happens with both my 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz bands. When I check the `Logs`, it shows as below, some `rfkill`. I just connected ethernet cable and is connected to the internet.

The interesting part is, I am able to connect to my Android WiFi hotspot while my router's is not getting connected. Another strange behaviour is that it is a limited issue. Some times, router WiFi  gets connected without any issue at all. I am using `22.04` on HP Pavilion laptop.

Any help will be great. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: "soft blocked" means it is software that is doing this. "Recently I started actively using UFW / gufw" That could totally be the reason ... I would start by disabling ufw. If that did it your rules are doing this. I do not know if it is possible to find out what started rfkill :P that would be something useful.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind , I have set no rules at the moment for gufw / ufw. Will try disabling ufw. But if it is ufw, it should block it all the time, right? I am able to connected to router WiFi at times.